# Ayuda con virus en WordPress

Tags: wordpress, seo

tengo un problema con un sitio en Wordpress. Hace poco nos infectaron con un virus el cual redirigia en la búsqueda de google a otro sitio. Eso lo se logro eliminar, pero se quedo una afectación, que es cuando muestra el resultado del sitio, muestra unos enlaces en la parte de abajo que desconozco y no se de donde los toma, si hay alguien que me pueda ayudar porfa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No creas que es tan fácil limpiar un hackeo en Wordpress. Crees que todo está bien y de repente te encuentras cosas como las que comentas. Lo más recomendable es instalar todo WP desde cero, y luego revisar todo y subirlo una vez revisado. El problema es que Wordpress funciona con muchos archivos en relación y a veces el hacker mete código malicioso en archivos que ni te imaginas y cuando WP llama a ese archivo el hackeo se revierte. O se disimula en archivos que son aparentemente imágenes del sitio. [Revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/215708/29967), creo que puede ayudarte.

Comment: Te has asegurado de que Google haya vuelto a indexar la web con los nuevos links?. Es posible que, aunque tu wordpress esté limpio, eso que se muestra este en caché de Google, y estés intentando arreglar algo ya arreglado. Para asegurarte mirate el Google Search Console y a ver que te marca.

Comment: Intentare de nuevo en GSC, ya borre el sitio y lo cargue de nuevo, dice que espere unos dias a ver que pasa

Answer (score 0):

Intenta instalando Wordfence. Además te servirá para futuros posibles ataques. Cuando lo instales dale a escanear y te escaneará todos los archivos de wordpress en busca de contenido malicioso.

Ademas, si no quieres esperar a que google actualice las urls por si solo, puede entrar en google search console y hacer que fuerce la actualización de los enlaces en su buscador.