# Sitio Pirateado Google Search

Tags: wordpress, plugin, google-search-console

Desde hace unos días Google ha calificado mi página web como sitio comprometido debido según a su Search Console a una inyección de URL (estas páginas parecen haber sido creadas por un hacker con la intención de realizar prácticas fraudulentas en los resultados de búsqueda).

Comment: Y cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: La inyección de URL es uno de los ataques más difíciles de detectar, y además puede que no se quede ahí, sino que hayan plagado tu sitio de archivos dañiños. Esto ocurre casi siempre, en el caso de Wordress, por tener una instalación sin actualizar durante mucho tiempo, o por tener plugins viejos o inseguros. [Lee esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/215708/29967), quizá puede aportar algunas ideas para afrontar este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno este es el proceso a seguir.

Descarga una versión actualizada de wordpress limpia.

Remplaza las carpetas wp-admin, wp-includes, y todos los archivos de la raiz sin tocar wp-content y tampoco el archivo wp-config. Si haces esto puedes perder información valiosa.

Una vez remplaces los archivos, debes de mirar en la carpeta wp-content/uploads, carpeta por carpeta archivos php, que no deben de estar allí y eliminarlos.

Cuando hagas esto, instala un plugin de seguridad puede ser "Sucury" y realiza un análisis, esto te ayudara a mirar si hay archivos inyectados que no correspondan a Wordpress.

Por ultimo debes limpiar la plantilla de tu sitio, también mirando archivo por archivo si hay alguna inyección de PHP, más que todo en el archivo, index.php, functions.php, header.php y footer.php. Sin embargo miralo todo.

Cuando todo este limpio, cambia las contraseñas del administrador y CPanel, y majora los permisos de las carpetas del wordpress.

Es un proceso lento pero es recomendado que siempre tengas tus plugins (Ojala de pago) actualizados y no los descargues de fuentes inseguras.

Cuando todo este proceso termine, ve a Google Webmaster Console y solicita la revisión nuevamente de tu sitio web.